# <matTabContent> is not showing any data on IE11, while for Chrome its work like a charm

Tags: javascript, angular-material, internet-explorer-11, angular8

I am using Angular 8 and Angular Material

With Google Chrome its work fine, when I open in IE11, clicking any of the tab 
only **mat-tab-label** remaining but the content is hide.

I tried many things but I didn't have luck.

```
<mat-tab-group class="form-wizard" [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex"
(selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)">
//tab 1
<mat-tab>
  <ng-template mat-tab-label>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="8px">
      <span class="badge primary">1</span>
      <span>Family’s Expenses</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <div class="row row-border" >
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 mb-lg-0 mb-3">
      Final expenses 
      <a style="cursor:pointer" (click)="showDialog('cash1')" class="red-more">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
      <input class="text" currencyMask [options]="{allowNegative :false ,precision: 0 }"
        (keyup)="onBlur($event)">
    </div>
  </div>

</mat-tab>
//tab 2
<mat-tab>
  <ng-template mat-tab-label>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="8px">
      <span class="badge primary">2</span>
      <span>Total Annual Income</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <div class="row row-border">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 mb-lg-0 mb-3">
      Monthly income to take care of your family
      <a style="cursor:pointer" (click)="showDialog('income1')" class="red-more">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
      <input class="text" currencyMask [options]="{allowNegative :false ,precision: 0 }"
        (keyup)="onBlur($event)">
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Do you have any error on the console log (IE11)?

Comment: no. 

just a empty dom.

its seems data is not loading

Comment: Could you share the JSFiddle ?

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal sample which can reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue so that we can have a test and see how to help? You could use online code editor like StackBlitz. With only the html code, we can't reproduce the issue. Thanks for your understanding.